# Accessing Swift Arrays From Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, swift

I have a Swift class `User` and a Swift class `Artist`. A `User` can have many `Artists` and this relationship and these classes are implemented in the code below.

```
import UIKit

class Artist: NSObject {
    var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

class User: NSObject {

    var artists = [Artist]()
    var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

}
```

I need to be able to edit the artists array from Objective C. When I try to add an object to the artists array, Xcode tells me that the artists array is of type `NSArray` and cannot be modified. Is there a way to access this array as an NSMutableArray?

Comment: You're doing it wrong. There should not be any code outside the User class that modifies the artists array. Other classes should not even know that the artists array exists. Add methods to add/remove artists to the User class and call those from your Obj-C code.

Answer (score 2):

In Objective C, you can just copy the array to a mutable array:

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArtists = [artists mutableCopy];
[mutableArtists addObject:...]; // Add your objects to mutableArtists or make other changes.
NSArray *artistsToReturn = [mutableArtists copy];
return artistsToReturn;
```

Alternatively, you could cast your Swift array to be of NSMutableArray type in the class definition, if you are happy for it to work as an NSMutableArray rather than having the usual Swift mutable array characteristics:

```
var artists : NSMutableArray = [Artist]()
```

In Swift, you could also instead create an NSMutableArray copy of the array, that you could then access from your Objective-C class instead, if that was more convenient.:

```
var mutableArtists = NSMutableArray(artists)
```